# How can I find out who the winner is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 divs that move at a different, random speed every time.
Now I really don't know how I can find out who the fastest is/the first to reach the goal.
There's also a box where you can choose which horse you want to bet, so I have to compare the winner and my horse to see if I win. Help would be really appreciated :)

```js
var eins = document.getElementById("pf1");
var zwei = document.getElementById("pf2");
var drei = document.getElementById("pf3");
var vier = document.getElementById("pf4");

var randomMultiplier = 7;


document.querySelector("[class='buttoncss']").addEventListener("click", function() {

  move(eins, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(zwei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(drei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(vier, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
});

var stopp = 1036;

function move(element, entfernung) {

  element.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).left, 10) + entfernung) + "px";
  if (parseInt(element.style.left, 10) <= stopp) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      move(element, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
    }, 40);
  }
}
```

```css
.auswahl select {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.auswahl {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20em;
  top: 35.61em;
}

.eingabe {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.8em;
  top: 32.8em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.ok {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32em;
  top: 69.5%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 16px
}

.einsatz {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 19px
}

.inl1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 1.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 7.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 13.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 19.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.buttoncss {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.buttoncss:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70em;
}

.content1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #8547BD;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #D357BB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content1" id="pf1"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl1">Pferdename 1</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content2" id="pf2"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl2">Pferdename 2 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content3" id="pf3"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl3">Pferdename 3 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content4" id="pf4"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl4">Pferdename 4</p>
<br>
<form>
  <p class="einsatz">Wie hoch ist dein Wetteinsatz?</p>
  <input id="einsatz" type="number" placeholder="0" class="eingabe" />


  <p class="einsatz">Auf welches Pferd willst du wetten?</p>
  <div class="auswahl">
    <select>
      <option selected style="color:gray;">bitte wählen</option>
      <option>Pferdename 1</option>
      <option>Pferdename 2</option>
      <option>Pferdename 3</option>
      <option>Pferdename 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <input class="buttoncss" type="button" value="Starte das Rennen!">
</form>
```

Comment: you have a condition checking stopp. the first that doesn't satisfy it (else part) would be the winner. if you create a method declareWinner(element) there you can check against your bet

Answer (score 1):

The below condition becomes `false` when a div reaches the end, so check the opposite (`else`).

```
if (parseInt(element.style.left, 10) <= stopp)  {
```

Within that, use a variable to find if it is the first div where that condition is not `true`. Then compare the `id` of that div to the one the user chose to find if they were correct.

```js
var eins = document.getElementById("pf1");
var zwei = document.getElementById("pf2");
var drei = document.getElementById("pf3");
var vier = document.getElementById("pf4");

var randomMultiplier = 7;


document.querySelector("[class='buttoncss']").addEventListener("click", function() {

  move(eins, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(zwei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(drei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(vier, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
});

var first, correct, stopp = 1036;

function move(element, entfernung) {

  element.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).left, 10) + entfernung) + "px";
  if (parseInt(element.style.left, 10) <= stopp) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      move(element, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
    }, 40);
  } else {
    if (!first) {
      first = element.id;
      correct = first == "pf" + document.getElementById("einsatz").value;

      console.log(first);
      console.log(correct);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.auswahl select {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.auswahl {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20em;
  top: 35.61em;
}

.eingabe {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.8em;
  top: 32.8em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.ok {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32em;
  top: 69.5%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 16px
}

.einsatz {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 19px
}

.inl1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 1.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 7.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 13.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 19.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.buttoncss {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.buttoncss:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70em;
}

.content1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #8547BD;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #D357BB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content1" id="pf1"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl1">Pferdename 1</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content2" id="pf2"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl2">Pferdename 2 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content3" id="pf3"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl3">Pferdename 3 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content4" id="pf4"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl4">Pferdename 4</p>
<br>
<form>
  <p class="einsatz">Wie hoch ist dein Wetteinsatz?</p>
  <input id="einsatz" type="number" placeholder="0" class="eingabe" />


  <p class="einsatz">Auf welches Pferd willst du wetten?</p>
  <div class="auswahl">
    <select>
      <option selected style="color:gray;">bitte wählen</option>
      <option>Pferdename 1</option>
      <option>Pferdename 2</option>
      <option>Pferdename 3</option>
      <option>Pferdename 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <input class="buttoncss" type="button" value="Starte das Rennen!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an `else` block to this if `(parseInt(element.style.left, 10) <= stopp)` and the first horse to hit this `else` block is the winner.

I've add three variables to your code:

```
let foundWinner = false;
let selectedOption;
const select = document.querySelector("select");
```

On button click I will set value of `selectedOption`.

**NOTE:** You should do this when the button is clicked, because you don't want the user to change his/her selection after clicking the button.

```js
var eins = document.getElementById("pf1");
var zwei = document.getElementById("pf2");
var drei = document.getElementById("pf3");
var vier = document.getElementById("pf4");

var randomMultiplier = 7;
let foundWinner = false;
let selectedOption;
const select = document.querySelector("select");

document.querySelector("[class='buttoncss']").addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  selectedOption = select.value;
  
  move(eins, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(zwei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(drei, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
  move(vier, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
});

var stopp = 1036;

function move(element, entfernung) {

  element.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).left, 10) + entfernung) + "px";
  if (parseInt(element.style.left, 10) <= stopp) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      move(element, Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomMultiplier));
    }, 40);
  } else if(!foundWinner) {
    const winningHorse = element.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerText.trim();
  console.log("Winner Is:", winningHorse);
  console.log(selectedOption === winningHorse ? "You Won" : "You lose");
  foundWinner = true;
}
}
```

```css
.auswahl select {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.auswahl {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20em;
  top: 35.61em;
}

.eingabe {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.8em;
  top: 32.8em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.ok {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32em;
  top: 69.5%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 16px
}

.einsatz {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 19px
}

.inl1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 1.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 7.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 13.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.inl4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1200px;
  top: 19.7em;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px
}

.buttoncss {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.buttoncss:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70em;
}

.content1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5C88A3;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #736FB9;
}

.content3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #8547BD;
}

.content4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #D357BB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content1" id="pf1"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl1">Pferdename 1</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content2" id="pf2"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl2">Pferdename 2 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content3" id="pf3"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl3">Pferdename 3 </p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content4" id="pf4"></div>
</div>
<p class="inl4">Pferdename 4</p>
<br>
<form>
  <p class="einsatz">Wie hoch ist dein Wetteinsatz?</p>
  <input id="einsatz" type="number" placeholder="0" class="eingabe" />


  <p class="einsatz">Auf welches Pferd willst du wetten?</p>
  <div class="auswahl">
    <select>
      <option selected style="color:gray;">bitte wählen</option>
      <option>Pferdename 1</option>
      <option>Pferdename 2</option>
      <option>Pferdename 3</option>
      <option>Pferdename 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <input class="buttoncss" type="button" value="Starte das Rennen!">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```